# Check two arrays for cyclic permutations in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to check if an int array is a cyclic permutation of another (or is equal) efficiently in C#.

For example, the following arrays are cyclic permutations: `{1,2,3}`, `{2,3,1}` and `{3,1,2}`, whereas `{2,1,3}` is not. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a brute force method in head but I can't figure something faster :/

Comment: Can the numbers be duplicated? That is, what if we have `{1, 1, 2}` and `{1, 2, 1}`, is that a match?

Comment: I note that this is usually called a *cyclic permutation*, not a *circular permutation*.

Comment: You ask for an efficient solution without saying what you mean by "efficient".  Asymptotically efficient?  Producing low memory pressure? Fast time to reject obvious bad matches?  What's your measure of efficiency?

Comment: You say you have a brute force method, but you don't say what it is. **Help us help you**.  There's no point in us replicating work you've already done and rejected.  **Ask a more specific question**.

Comment: There are two versions of this problem. The general problem is, you have a bunch of pairs of arrays (a, b), (c, d), (e, f), and so on, and you wish to see which pairs have the property that (x, y) has x a cyclic permutation of y or not.  The more specific problem is: you have a specific array "a", and you have a whole bunch of arrays b, c, d, e, f, g,... and you want to know which of b, c, d, e, f, g are cyclic permutations of "a".  Those are not the same problem! There may be techniques to preprocess "a" so that the solution is more efficient for each possible case.

Comment: In short, **you have given us nowhere near enough information to do any better than the brute force solution**.  Again, help us help you.  Ask a clear, pertinent question that describes the actual problem you're trying to solve, what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Also: problems like this are studied because they are germane to matching DNA fragments. What research have you already done?  What papers on the subject have you read, and why have you rejected the techniques they describe?

Comment: The numbers can't be duplicated

Comment: Then just do the obvious linear time solution. Do a linear search of the second array for the first number in the first array, and now you can pair off array elements and compare them for equality. There is no more efficient solution than that. Assuming you've already taken the easy outs, the worst case is that you're going to have to walk every element of the arrays twice and the best case is once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method should produce the desired behaviour:

```cs
bool IsCyclicPermutation(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[0]) // Potential starting point of cycle found
        {
            bool isCyclic = true;
            for (int j = 1; j < b.Length && isCyclic; j++)
            {
                if (a[(j + i) % a.Length] != b[j]) isCyclic = false;
            }
            if (isCyclic) return true; // Cycle found
        }
    }

    return false; // No cycles found
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If it is the case that there are no duplicate numbers, you can use the modified code as below for slightly better performance:

```cs
bool IsCyclicPermutation(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[0]) // Starting point of potential cycle found
        {
            bool isCyclic = true;
            for (int j = 1; j < b.Length && isCyclic; j++)
            {
                if (a[(j + i) % a.Length] != b[j]) isCyclic = false;
            }
            return isCyclic;
        }
    }

    return false; // No cycles found
}
```

---

The following tests have been performed:

```cs
var arr1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var arr2 = new int[] {2, 3, 1};
var arr3 = new int[] {3, 1, 2};
var arr4 = new int[] {2, 1, 3};

IsCyclicPermutation(arr1, arr1); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr1, arr2); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr1, arr3); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr2, arr1); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr2, arr2); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr2, arr3); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr3, arr1); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr3, arr2); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr3, arr3); // True
IsCyclicPermutation(arr4, arr1); // False
IsCyclicPermutation(arr4, arr2); // False
IsCyclicPermutation(arr4, arr3); // False
```

As for performance, it's hard to tell without something to compare it against, although I do believe it is O(n) with n being the size of the input arrays.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed

Comment: @Couroux take a look at my edit for an improved function to be used when the arrays don't contain duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int[] array2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        int tmp = array1[0];
        int index = Array.IndexOf(array2, tmp);
        int n = array1.Length;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (index + i < array1.Length)
            {
                if (array1[i] != array2[index+i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are not equal");
                    break;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (array1[i] != array2[index + i - n])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are not equal");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

I assume the length of the arrays and their elements are the same. The above code does the job at O(n). Double check the index!

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

[DotNetFiddle Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQ6a8O)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test1 = new [] {1, 2, 3};
        var test2 = new [] {2, 3, 1};
        var test3 = new [] {3, 1, 2};
        var test4 = new [] {2, 1, 3};

        test1.IsCiruclarPermutation(test2);
        test1.IsCiruclarPermutation(test3);
        test2.IsCiruclarPermutation(test1);
        test2.IsCiruclarPermutation(test3);
        test3.IsCiruclarPermutation(test1);
        test3.IsCiruclarPermutation(test2);

        test4.IsCiruclarPermutation(test1);
        test4.IsCiruclarPermutation(test2);
        test4.IsCiruclarPermutation(test3);
    }
}

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static bool IsCiruclarPermutation(this int[] source, int[] dest)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Join(",", source) + " is a Ciruclar Permutation of ");
        Console.Write(string.Join(",", dest));

        var left = source.ToList();
        var right = dest.ToList();
        right.AddRange(dest);

        var result = false;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < left.Count; idx++)      
        {
            var compareTo = right.Skip(idx).Take(left.Count);
            result = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(left, compareTo);
            if (result) break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("  " + result.ToString());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1,2,3 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 2,3,1  True
>
> 1,2,3 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 3,1,2  True
>
> 2,3,1 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 1,2,3  True
>
> 2,3,1 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 3,1,2  True
>
> 3,1,2 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 1,2,3  True
>
> 3,1,2 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 2,3,1  True
>
> 2,1,3 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 1,2,3  False
>
> 2,1,3 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 2,3,1  False
>
> 2,1,3 is a Ciruclar Permutation of 3,1,2  False

Comment: You say that there is work to do to compare arrays of different lengths. Can you give an example of two arrays of different lengths where one is a permutation of the other?

Comment: I note that none of your test cases look at test1 being a permutation of test1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hard problem, convert it to simple problem, following code use linkedlist to solve the problem, it's not best for performance, but easy to understand.

```
public class SameTest<T>
{
    public bool TestCircularArray(IEnumerable<T> array1, IEnumerable<T> array2)
    {
        if (array1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array1");
        if (array2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("array2");

        // if they are the same, the length must be the same
        if (array1.Count() != array2.Count())
            return false;

        // two empty array assume to same
        if (!array1.Any())
            return true;

        // convert array2 to linkedlist
        var linkedList = new LinkedList<T>(array2);

        LinkedListNode<T> node = null;

        foreach (T item1 in array1)
        {
            // first find the element in link
            if (node == null)
            {
                node = linkedList.Find(item1);
                if (node == null)
                    return false;
                continue;
            }

            node = node.Next;
            // reach tail move to head
            if (node == null)
                node = linkedList.First;

            if (!item1.Equals(node.Value))
                return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int[] array1 = {2, 3, 1};
    int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] array3 = {2, 1, 3};

    var tester = new SameTest<int>();

    var result = tester.TestCircularArray(array1, array2);

    Assert.AreEqual(true, result);

    result = tester.TestCircularArray(array2, array3);

    Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
}
```